# In Ruby is there a way to get the index of an item in an array that consists of structs?

Tags: ruby

With a normal array, I can use the `arrayname.find_index('whatimlookingfor')` to get the position within the array.

I can't figure out how to do this when the elements of the array are Struct's.

Scenario: I have a struct that consists of an ID and the Filename. In one function I need to find within that array the ID of a different file than the one I'm currently processing. I know the other filename, so what I was hoping that I could do something like:

`arrayname.filename.find_index(parsedfilename)`

But this obviously fails. Without iterating through the entire array is there a way to quickly reference the index of where the match happens? Or am I out of luck because the array is a collection of structs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-find_index) (same as `find_index`) takes a block in which you can code up any true/false logic for your finder. To find the index of the first item whose filename does not match `parsedfilename`...

```
found_index = items.index { |item| item.filename != parsedfilename }
```

Many methods which work with Arrays and [Enumerables](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) also take blocks.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware that I could do that with Structs.

Comment: Wayne, note `S = Struct.new(:filename); s = S.new('cat') #=> #<struct S filename="cat">; s.filename #=> "cat"`.